# When attempting to move a Player component on a hexgrid, how can we remove the original player?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We're attempting to make a game using a React-hexgrid. We render the player component on the hexgrid based on preset random locations and spawn the player. When we want to move the player, we're testing a MovePlayer function that will move player1 to the clicked cell. We set the original playerlocation to null but the original player still remains. Why is this, and how can we remove the original player after clicking on a different cell, and be able to click that same cell to bring the player back if we want to move them back?

Here is my MovePlayer function.

```
const MovePlayer = (playerNumber, q, r, i, setClickedPlayer, playerLocations, setPlayerLocations, randomPlace1, randomPlace2) => {
    // Function logic here, using 'playerNumber' to determine which player to move
    switch (playerNumber) {
        case 1:
            console.log('Player 1 Moves!')

            // Remove Player
            setPlayerLocations(prevLocations => ({
                ...prevLocations,
                [`player${playerNumber}`]: null,
            }));

            setTimeout(() => {
            const adjacentCells = AdjacentTiles(q, r);
            if (adjacentCells.includes(playerLocations.player1)) {

                // Add player to new location
                setPlayerLocations(prevLocations => ({
                    ...prevLocations,
                    [`player${playerNumber}`]: i,
                }));

                console.log("Added a player to cell index: ", i);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Not adding a player to cell index: ", i);
            }
        }, 2000);
            break;
    }
};
```

And our hexagon cell.

```
const randomPlace1 = PlayerSpawn1();
const randomPlace2 = PlayerSpawn2();


const Cell = ({ q, r, i }) => {
    const [clickedPlayer, setClickedPlayer] = useState(null);

    const [playerLocations, setPlayerLocations] = useState({
        player1: randomPlace1.i,
        player2: randomPlace2.i,
    });


    return (
        <Hexagon onClick={() => {
            HandleClick(q, r, i, setClickedPlayer, randomPlace1, randomPlace2, playerLocations,);

            MovePlayer(1, q, r, i, setClickedPlayer, playerLocations, setPlayerLocations, randomPlace1, randomPlace2);
            
            // MovePlayer(2, q, r, i, setClickedPlayer, playerLocations, setPlayerLocations, randomPlace1, randomPlace2);

        }} key={i} q={q} r={r}>
            {<Text>{i} {q} {r}</Text>}
            {playerLocations.player1 === i ? <Player playerNumber={1} /> : null}
            {playerLocations.player2 === i ? <Player playerNumber={2} /> : null}


        </Hexagon>
    )
}
```